# Show page number only for headings of level 1 in the Table of Contents

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, page-numbers

I have a TOC that is driven from 3 heading levels. I want all the levels on the TOC but on the page number for heading 1.

From the headers on the document:

> - Document Number SPS SOP 2002
>
>   - Revision/Approval Date: 10/2016
>
>     - Method: Direct Observation

What I get in the TOC:

> Document Number SPS SOP 2002.............5
>   Revision/Approval Date: 10/2016................5
>   Method: Direct Observation.........................5

What I want from the TOC:

> Document Number SPS SOP 2002...........5
>   Revision/Approval Date: 10/2016
>   Method: Direct Observation

Comment: was in a hurry - hopefully this clears it up.  Nedd TOC but most items are on the same page in the section, so need the headers listed but want to delete the page number for levels 2 and 3 to clean the TOC up a bit

Answer (score 4):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to show field codes and add the following switch to the TOC:

```
{ TOC \n 3-4 }
```

As described in the [Word documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-toc-table-of-contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c)

> \n Levels Omits page numbers from the table of contents. Page numbers
>   are omitted from all levels unless a range of entry levels is
>   specified. For example, { TOC \n 3-4 } omits page numbers from levels
>   3 and 4. Delete this switch to include page numbers.